# Looking for a fantasy drama about a girl in a fantasy land with a walrus

Tags: story-identification, tv

Well I was looking for a fantasy/sci fi programme I watched recently (within the last 2/3 years recently) which had a girl that was imagining she was in a fantasy land, and I believe she had a walrus with her as well? I know I’m being vague but any help at all please.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where did you see this?  (What country, what source?)  Was it in English or another language?  Live-action or animated?  How long was it?

Comment: Sure it was a walrus? Does the name Martin Tenbones ring any bells?

Comment: Yes I think that’s him!

Comment: Nice one @JiminyCricket.

Comment: Haha how did you get that @jiminycricket on so little information?

Comment: Had a dream about it last night ;)

Comment: @Slennon - If [Jiminy Cricket.'s answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/277825/122024) is correct, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The Sandman](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1751634/) TV series (Netflix, by Neil Gaiman).

The character you mention resembles Martin Tenbones (voice: [Lenny Henry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0377901/)):

[image: Walrus-like creature accompanied by a young woman in a period dress.]

<sup>[wegotthiscovered.com](https://wegotthiscovered.com/tv/every-resident-of-the-dreaming-we-meet-in-the-sandman/) 2023, via Netflix. Fair usage.</sup>

The reality they currently inhabit is at the conjunction of the dreams of various characters.

The point of view is that from the dream of a young girl who's in search of her brother, who is also, in a way looking for her. She's pictured right of centre here:

[image: Montage of cast.]

<sup>[fanfiadict.com](https://fanfiaddict.com/sff-addicts-tv-club-the-sandman-s01-review-2/), 2023 fair usage.</sup>

The Sandman of the title is centre, Lord of Dreams. There's more going on than just that though.

Available on Netflix, with a second season already commissioned.

Comment: I feel this answer is slightly misleading; could it be you watched the show a long time ago? Barbie is first and foremost a _housemate_ of Rose (the girl looking for her brother), and Rose happens to wander in Barbie's dream, where Barbie is dreaming of herself as being a princess in the middle of a quest.

Comment: Ah, yes. There are layers of reality and the like. I forgot it was a TV show for a while. @MatthieuM. I'll edit accordingly.